# Previous Nth occurrence

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I've an Excel query below I'm trying to get the value of a cell from previous nth occurrence from current cell.

Basically I'm trying to get the value for the last week same day,
as can be seen from below table, I want Sales of branches same day last week.

By search able to get the Nth occurrence but not by match and previous Nth occurrence based on current cell.

same day, last week:
[image: same day, last week]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Index()` and `Match()` for this purpose.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:D, MATCH(B1-7,B:B),4),"")
```

Place this formula in `E1` and drag down. Obviously, your first 7 rows in column E will be blank since there is nothing to match against (hence the reason for the `IFERROR()` portion.

[image]

---

In response to [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49090425/previous-nth-occurrence/49090525?noredirect=1#comment85285400_49090525), I failed to see that there were two sets of criteria. You can use a formula array to do what you need.

> **Warning:** It's recommended that you do not include the entire column as shown in the below formula. This can decrease performance - especially when calculation is set to automatic.
>   You should include a significant portion of the column that covers all of your data rather than the entire column (ie: instead of `$A:$D`, you could use `$A1:$D500`)

Enter the following formula in **A1**, but **do not press enter yet**:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A:$D, MATCH(1,($B:$B=B1-7)*($C:$C=C1),0),4),"")
```

Your cursor should still be blinking in the formula bar. Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> simultaneously.

If done correctly, the formula in the bar should now be in between these brackets: `{}`.

This is what the final result should look like:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($A:$D, MATCH(1,($B:$B=B1-7)*($C:$C=C1),0),4),"")}
```

> You cannot "manually" input the brackets, you must do it with the key combo provided!!

Now, you may drag down as needed

Comment: Hi Davis, Thanks for your response. I've a condition to match Branch also as in my given sheet I've 2 branches "Branch-1" and "Branch-2", So the formula should match the Date as well as the Branch to get the result.

Comment: @sak I apologize, didn't see the other criteria - updated (see second portion of answer). If this was helpful in resolving your issue, feel free to check the checkmark to left of the answer! :)

Comment: Hi Davis, Many thanks for your support, sorry was late response was caught up with work.

Comment: Hi Davis, Many thanks for your support, sorry for late response was caught up with work. Your formula is working for me. I was unable to concatenate the match condition. Thanks Again, really appreciate your help.

Comment: Glad to hear that @sak! Thanks for the feedback